# tests fail on simple microservice and entity

Tags: jhipster

Running "mvn clean test" after creating a fresh microservice and adding a simple entity.

Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [net/foo/bar/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started

```
   {
      "generator-jhipster": {
        "jhipsterVersion": "3.5.1",
        "baseName": "foobar",
        "packageName": "net.foo.bar",
        "packageFolder": "net/foo/bar",
        "serverPort": "8082",
        "authenticationType": "uaa",
        "uaaBaseName": "uaa",
        "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
        "databaseType": "sql",
        "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
        "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
        "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
        "buildTool": "maven",
        "jwtSecretKey": "*",
        "enableTranslation": false,
        "applicationType": "microservice",
        "testFrameworks": [
          "gatling",
          "cucumber"
        ],
        "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
        "skipClient": true,
        "skipUserManagement": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: I looked into this and there's actually an error above the liquibase problem.  It looks like the test profile can't find the UAA server.  I opened [an issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3982), thank you for testing out the beta features.

Comment: A temporary workaround until we fix it in the project is to add `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "eureka.client.enabled")` above MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration, getting an oauth key from the UAA isn't possible without eureka